# File Uploaded Despite Having Code to Eliminate Same Files ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, razor, google-drive-api

I have a code that accepts file upload, download, delete to the Google Drive. Basically, if it is a same file, then the user is alerted that it is the same file. If it is a new file, it will be uploaded to the Google Drive and the user will be alerted that it is uploaded. This is the code for my uploadFile method.

```
<script>
    $('#fileUpload').click(function (e) {
            if ($('#file').val() === "") {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Nothing',
                    text: 'No file selected',
                    type: 'error',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Again!!',
                    timer: 4000
                });
            }
            else {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/UploadFile",
                    type: 'Post',
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result) {
                            Swal.fire({
                                title: 'Wait awhile...',
                                text: 'File will be uploaded shortly',
                                type: 'success',
                                confirmButtonText: 'Okay, cool',
                                timer: 4000
                            })
                            location.href = "/Home/GetGoogleDriveFiles";
                        } else if (result) {
                            alert("Upload not sucess");
                        }
                    },
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                });
            }
        }
    );
</script>
```

This is for my controller FileUpload. It basically will pass the value of true or false from the C# code to the controller which will then pass to the result part.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    bool kk = GoogleDriveFilesRepository.FileUpload(file);
    return Json(kk, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is my C# upload file code.

```
public static bool FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        DriveService service = GetService();

        string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/GoogleDriveFiles"),Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
        file.SaveAs(path);

        HashGenerator(path);  
        if(compareHash(HashGenerator(path)))
        {
            var FileMetaData = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
            FileMetaData.Name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            FileMetaData.MimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);
            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;

            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                request = service.Files.Create(FileMetaData, stream, FileMetaData.MimeType);
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;              
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Now , the issue that I am facing is that when I upload the file, even though it is the same file, it will be uploaded although I assume that I have coded in a way that it would not accept the same file that already exists in the Google Drive. I am not too sure which part I am missing out.**

**EDIT: Hash Generator and Compare Hash Code**

```
public static string HashGenerator(string path)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "null").ToLower();
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool compareHash(string path)
    {

        DriveService service = GetService();
        FilesResource.ListRequest FileListRequest = service.Files.List();
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = FileListRequest.Execute().Files;
        List<GoogleDriveFiles> FileList = new List<GoogleDriveFiles>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.Equals(path))
            {
                return false;

            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

**EDIT 2**

```
public static bool FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            DriveService service = GetService();

           string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/GoogleDriveFiles"),Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            file.SaveAs(path);

            var hash =  HashGenerator(path);  
            if(compareHash(path))
            {
                var FileMetaData = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
                FileMetaData.Name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                FileMetaData.MimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;

                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    request = service.Files.Create(FileMetaData, stream, FileMetaData.MimeType);
                    request.Fields = "id";
                    request.Upload();
                }

             return true;
            }
            return false;              
        }
        return false;
    } 

    public static string HashGenerator(string path)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool compareHash(string hash)
    {

        DriveService service = GetService();
        FilesResource.ListRequest FileListRequest = service.Files.List();
        FileListRequest.Fields = "*";
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = FileListRequest.Execute().Files;
        List<GoogleDriveFiles> FileList = new List<GoogleDriveFiles>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.Md5Checksum.Equals(hash))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;       
    }
```

I will also include the code for my controller and razor for file upload.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        bool kk = GoogleDriveFilesRepository.FileUpload(file);
        return Json(kk, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
                         event.preventDefault();
                        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Home/UploadFile",
                            type: 'Post',
                            success: function (result) {
                                if (result) {
                                    Swal.fire({
                                        title: 'Wait awhile...',
                                        text: 'File will be uploaded shortly',
                                        type: 'success',
                                        confirmButtonText: 'Okay, cool',
                                        timer: 4000
                                    })
                                    location.href = "/Home/GetGoogleDriveFiles";

                                } else {
                                    Swal.fire({
                                        title: 'OOps',
                                        text: 'File unable to be uploaded shortly',
                                        type: 'error',
                                        confirmButtonText: 'Okay, then',
                                        timer: 4000
                                    })
                                    location.href = "/Home/GetGoogleDriveFiles";

                                }
                            },
                            data: formData,
                            cache: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false
                        });
```

It still accepts the same file even though it had already existed..

**EDIT 3**
[image]

I uploaded a png called virtual_box image and its hash generated by my MD5 was 6da442ab0fad247e00d1ea86f246beb2 and when I comapred with the Google Drive hash, it was the same.
[image]

Comment: Could you please include the source for `compareHash` and `HashGenerator` in your question?

Comment: uploaded where?  When you post the form data, the file is uploaded.  The "save" part copies the file to a certain location.  The "compareHash" function doesn't seem to take two arguments, so it's not clear that it's comparing anything.

Comment: @user7217806 I have already added the hash generator and compare hash code. Take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @pcalkins It will be uploaded to the Google Drive. I have uploaded the code for the compare hash and generate hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this check in your `compareHash` method is incorrect.

```
if (file.Equals(path))
{
    return false;
}
```

As you commented, Md5Checksum is the property you need to check against.

```
if (file.Md5Checksum.Equals(path))
{
    return false;
}
```

Also, your `HashGenerator` method contains this line:

```
return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "null").ToLower();
```

I think `null` should be removed, so it's like this:

```
return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

The end result (with some refactoring) would be:

```
public static bool FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/GoogleDriveFiles"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
        file.SaveAs(path);

        var hash = CreateHash(path);
        if (!FileAlreadyExists(hash))
        {
            var fileMetaData = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
            fileMetaData.Name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            fileMetaData.MimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);

            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var service = GetService();
                request = service.Files.Create(fileMetaData, stream, fileMetaData.MimeType);
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

public static string CreateHash(string path)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }
    }
}

public static bool FileAlreadyExists(string hash)
{
    var service = GetService();
    var fileListRequest = service.Files.List();
    fileListRequest.Fields = "*";
    var files = fileListRequest.Execute().Files;

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if(file.Md5Checksum.Equals(hash))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT 3**
[image]

I uploaded a png called virtual_box image and its hash generated by my MD5 was 6da442ab0fad247e00d1ea86f246beb2 and when I comapred with the Google Drive hash, it was the same.
[image]

Comment: What i wanted was like the path is if the path of the file that was uploaded matches the files that are in the drive, then its a duplicate. A property of the file like the MD5 checksum of the file for example?

Comment: It returns  "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" pointing to the "return !file.Md5.checksum.equals(hash);

Comment: Edited my answer again, I forgot to add `fileListRequest.Fields = "*";`. Normally `*` shouldn't be necessary and you could specify the specific fields you want returned, but I tried with `md5Checksum` and that gave me an error.

Comment: It still uploads the same file even though it had prior existed in it... Strangely

Comment: I have updated the code as of yours but still the same result. Can you take a look?

Comment: Does the hash that's produced by CreateHash() match the Md5Checksum that's returned by Google?

Comment: Is there a way I can verify it? I am not sure if I can see my MD5 hash displayed. I can see the one generated by Google but not my own code of md5 hash

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, you could set a debugger breakpoint on this line `var hash = CreateHash(path);`, and see the value of `hash`.

Comment: Oh, when I check again, apparently, the hash from the CreateHash() matches the Google Drive hash

Comment: I believe it must be something wrong with the logic of the controller (true, false) since both the MD5 hashes match

Comment: I finally got it working. I missed the ! in (!CompareHash(hash)).. Thanks a lot @GJBisschop

Comment: Awesome, happy coding!